# Why dynamic_cast(this) in constructor not working and how to make it work?

Tags: c++

I am using CRTP to move common implementation of `D1` and `D2` into template, however, when constructing object I have to make call to overloaded function specific to each type.

The output of the following piece of code is

```
D 0x7ffc7d370538
D1 0
D 0x7ffc7d370540
D2 0
```

while expected output is

```
D 0x7ffc7d370538
D1 0x7ffc7d370538
D 0x7ffc7d370540
D2 0x7ffc7d370540
```

Why dynamic_cast returns nullptr? How to fix this code?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct B {
    B();
    virtual ~B() {}
};

struct D1 : B<D1> {
};

struct D2 : B<D2> {
};

void use(D1* d) { std::cout << "D1 " << d << std::endl; }
void use(D2* d) { std::cout << "D2 " << d << std::endl; }

template <typename Derived>
B<Derived>::B() {
    std::cout << "D " << this << std::endl;
    Derived* derivedThis = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this);
    use(derivedThis);
}

int main() {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
}
```

The only workaround which I found is the following

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Derived>
struct B {
    B();
    virtual ~B() {}
};

struct D1;
struct D2;

void use(D1* d) { std::cout << "D1 " << d << std::endl; }
void use(D2* d) { std::cout << "D2 " << d << std::endl; }

struct D1 : B<D1> {
    D1() { use(this); } # code duplication
};

struct D2 : B<D2> {
    D2() { use(this); } # code duplication
};

template <typename Derived>
B<Derived>::B() {
    std::cout << "D " << this << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    D1 d1;
    D2 d2;
}
```

However in my scenario it is too much code duplication to repeat call to function `use`. For example, there can be many derived classes, or many calls to functions similar to `use`.

Comment: General observation - do not mix run-time and compile-time polymorphism. In your particular case, when base constructor is called, derived is not constructed yet, so you should not cast to it.

Comment: @SergeyA I would like to use static_cast instead of dynamic_cast to make everything compile-time, but since dynamic_cast returns nullptr, it seems wrong approach.

Comment: See above, I added this detail as well.

Comment: @SergeyA Then is it possible to call function `use` in constructor without code duplication?

Comment: No, you can't call this `use` from constructor of `B`. It needs an object which is not yet constructed.

Comment: Could this question be rewritten without templates? I think it would be clearer

Comment: @TimRandall OP is attempting CRTP, so I doubt it could be rewritten without templates ;)

Comment: There should be no problem with `static_cast` so long as you don’t dereference those pointers.

Comment: @molbdnilo Unfortunately I dereference them and even use multiple non-virtual inheritance from non-abstract bases with data fields. Base class in the example is just one of such base classes.

Comment: @BhavinChirag Unfortunately you're not allowed to do that. There is no way around it.

Answer (score 5):

The immediate cause of your troubles is the fact than base class constructors are called before derived classes are constructed. Because of that, casting through `dynamic_class` in constructor leads to `nullptr`.

There is no way around it, you can't use an object of derived class from base class constructor.

On a side note, usually it is a design smell when both runtime and compile-time polymorphism are used in the same class. Stick to either of them.

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
template <typename Derived>
B<Derived>::B() {
```

you're about to initialize a instance of `B<Derived>`. In practice, this is initializing either the `B<D1>` base-class subobject of a `D1` instance, or the `B<D2>` base-class subobject of a `D2` instance.

Neither the `D1` nor the `D2` object can exist until after the base-class subobject has been successfully created. This means that during creation of the base-class subobject, the derived-class object *cannot yet* exist, and likewise the dynamic type of your base-class object *cannot yet* be the derived type.

If you want constructive suggestions on how to structure your code instead, you really need to explain what `use` is really supposed to do.